# Keras mobilenet implementation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to use mobilenet with different values for depth_multiplier(or resolution multiplier). These two lines of code give me the following error. Any idea what is going wrong here?

```
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet
basic_model = MobileNet(alpha=0.25, depth_multiplier=0.25, weights=None)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/Pedro/Desktop/Work/Smile/files/CVPR_2016_SMILES_DATA/test.py", line 2, in 
>       basic_model = MobileNet(alpha=0.25, depth_multiplier=0.25, weights=None)
>
> File "C:\Users\Pedro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\applications\mobilenet.py", line 456, in MobileNet
>       x = _depthwise_conv_block(x, 64, alpha, depth_multiplier, block_id=1)
>
> File "C:\Users\Pedro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\applications\mobilenet.py", line 654, in _depthwise_conv_block
>       name='conv_dw_%d' % block_id)(inputs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Pedro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 576, in **call**  self.build(input_shapes[0])
>
> File "C:\Users\Pedro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\applications\mobilenet.py", line 228, in build constraint=self.depthwise_constraint)
>
> File "C:\Users\Pedro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Pedro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 397, in add_weight weight = K.variable(initializer(shape),
>
> File "C:\Users\Pedro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers.py", line 212, in **call** dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)
>
> File "C:\Users\Pedro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 3627, in random_uniform dtype=dtype, seed=seed)
>
> File "C:\Users\Pedro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\random_ops.py", line 240, in random_uniform shape, dtype, seed=seed1, seed2=seed2)
>
> File "C:\Users\Pedro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_random_ops.py", line 247, in _random_uniform seed=seed, seed2=seed2, name=name)
>
> File "C:\Users\Pedro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 589, in apply_op param_name=input_name)
>
> File "C:\Users\Pedro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>    line 60, in _SatisfiesTypeConstraint
>        ", ".join(dtypes.as_dtype(x).name for x in allowed_list)))
>
> TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'shape' has DataType float32 not
>    in list of allowed values: int32, int64

From the [mobilent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04861.pdf): "The second hyper-parameter to reduce the computational cost of a neural network is a resolution multiplier ρ. We apply this to the input image and the internal representation of every layer is subsequently reduced by the same multiplier. In practice, we implicitly set ρ by setting the input resolution. We can now express the computational cost for the core layers of our network as depthwise separable convolutions with width multiplier α and resolution multiplier ρ:
DK · DK · αM · ρDF · ρDF + αM · αN · ρDF · ρDF (7)
where ρ ∈ (0, 1] which is typically set implicitly so that the input resolution of the network is 224, 192, 160 or 128. ρ = 1 is the baseline MobileNet and ρ < 1 are reduced computation MobileNets. Resolution multiplier has the effect of reducing computational cost by ρ^2."

And Keras has claimed the depth_multiplier is same as resolution multiplier in [here](https://keras.io/applications/#mobilenet) and [here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/mobilenet.py): "depth_multiplier: depth multiplier for depthwise convolution (also called the resolution multiplier)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is just bad naming and they are not the same. You can read more [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10349)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is at the bottom of the traceback call.

It expects an integer e.g 25 (a number without a decimal point) rather than a float e.g. 0.25

> depth_multiplier: The number of depthwise convolution output channels
>               for each input channel.
>               The total number of depthwise convolution output
>               channels will be equal to `filters_in * depth_multiplier`.

Reference: https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/mobilenet.py

Comment: But as mentioned in the [paper](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/mobilenet.py)  it can be values between 0 and 1.

Comment: By multiplying this value we intend to lower the number of parameters and in general make the model faster. By multiplying a bigger number than on 1, we will do exactly the opposite of that.

Comment: Not sure. Someone asked this question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327410/keras-implementation-of-resolution-multiplier-or-depth-multiplier-in-mobilenet

Comment: I edited the question I asked; Added more info to end of it from the mobilenet paper and also keras.